# How to create a Boost.Asio socket from a native socket?

Tags: c++, networking, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

I am merely trying to create a boost `ip::tcp::socket` from an existing native socket. In the [assign function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/assign.html), the first parameter must be a "protocol_type" and the second must be a "native_type", but it never explains what these are or gives an example of its use.

I'm guessing the second should be the socket descriptor, but I'd really appreciate clarification.

```
void SendData (int socket, std::string message)
{
    boost::asio::io_service ioserv;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket s(ioserv);
    s.assign(/* what goes here? */, /* ..and here? */);
    s.send(boost::asio::buffer(message));
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"Native type" is just the socket handle, in this case the int stored in "socket".

"Protocol type" is the the protocol.  For a TCP over standard IP using stream socket, this would be the return value from boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4().  Substitute as appropriate for datagram sockets, IPv6, etc.

So:

```
s.assign(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), socket);
```

Adjusted as appropriate for what you're trying to do.