# how to turn C++/CLI .Net socket into boost::asio socket?

Tags: .net, c++, sockets, boost, c++-cli

What I want is simple - code sample of creating new boost asio socket from C++/CLI .Net socket. How to create such thing?

Here is pseudo code of what I would like to do:

```
.net::socket a;
boost::asio::socket b;
b.assign(a.nativeWin32Socket());
```

Comment: What exactly wannt you to do? Replace a boost::asio socket by a .NET one?

Comment: no - I want havicg created and accepted connection on .Net side to turn .Net Socket instance into Boost::asio Socket.

Comment: What do you mean by "turn .NET Socket into Boost::asio Socket"? Porting at code level? Made a connection via TCP between them? Or?

Comment: Is there a boost version for .net out? Is there a .net version for c++ out? Else you will probably have to make an interop call. Is the C++ code in a separate dll? Or the .net code?

Comment: @Kabumbus: Probably you can use the value of the Handle property of the System::Net::Sockets::Socket class.

Comment: @RedX: there is a .NET version for C++ out: it's called C++/CLI and is referred to in the question. Kabumbus: wouldn't it be easier to just open a boost.asio socket directly?

Comment: @Fernandes Didn't know you could use C++/CLI with .Net. Learned something today, thanks.

Comment: @RedX : C++/CLI can't be used _without_ .Net.

Comment: @ildjam wouldn't that be the same as saying C++ cant be used without STL or boost?

Comment: @RedX : No, STL and Boost are libraries and thus optional; C++/CLI compiles to MSIL, and consequently **needs** the .Net CLR in order to to execute at all.

Comment: Isn't what I had shown you works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
b.assign(a.Handle.ToInt32());
```

Also note they you will need to use WSADuplicateSocket as you may get that both b and a will close the socket and point you don't expect.

So you need something like:

```
 SOCKET native = WSADuplicateSocket(a.Handle.ToInt32(),...);
 b.assign(native);
```

---

Full Answer (Tested)

```
SOCKET native = a->Handle.ToInt32();
// Now native is a real socket
b.assign(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), native);
```

Now it is good idea to duplicate the socket using WSADuplicateSocket:

Comment: May be you could provide us with some more full, tested code answer on related topic http://stackoverflow.com/q/7502644/434051 (Asio to .Net)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket/assign.html) to assign a native socket to a Boost asio socket. See the accepted answer to [How to create a Boost.Asio socket from a native socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671586/how-to-create-a-boost-asio-socket-from-a-native-socket).