# how to turn boost::asio socket into C++/CLI .Net socket?

Tags: .net, c++, sockets, boost, c++-cli

What I want is simple - code sample of creating new  C++/CLI .Net socket from boost asio socket. How to create such thing?

Here is pseudo code of what I would like to do:

```
.net::socket a;
boost::asio::socket b;
a.assign(b.nativeWin32Socket());
```

BTW: Here is how to [turn C++/CLI .Net socket into boost::asio socket.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361736/how-to-turn-c-cli-net-socket-into-boostasio-socket)

Comment: Not an option, the constructor that takes a (wrapped) socket handle is private.

Comment: @HansPassant: Yes, but [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145125.aspx) is public.  Warning: batteries not included.

Answer (score 8):

You can't 'detach' a Boost.ASIO socket. You can use the `native_handle()` member function to get a `SOCKET` handle from the `asio::socket` object, but you must ensure that the `asio::socket` object isn't destructed until you're done with the `SOCKET`. It continues to hold ownership of the native `SOCKET` and will close it when it's destructor is called.

Like André suggested, you could duplicate the socket handle. However, I wouldn't consider duplicating this socket safe, because Boost.ASIO automatically associates the native `SOCKET` handle with an I/O completion port. If the .NET Socket wrapper or some other code attempts to associate the duplicated socket with a different I/O completion port, an error will occur. I know that the .NET 2.0 Socket class does, in fact, associate the `SOCKET` handle with an I/O completion port for asynchronous operations. This may have changed in more recent versions, however.

Comment: Or use [`WSADuplicateSocket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741565(v=VS.85).aspx), then it doesn't matter when Boost closes the handle, you have an independent handle to the same socket that keeps it open.  (Assuming Boost calls `closesocket` and not `shutdown`)

Comment: Even if you can't detach the socket, you can still [duplicate the socket handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741565(v=VS.85).aspx) so that both abstractions can share the same socket through two different handles.

Comment: The Boost implementation associates the SOCKET handle with an I/O completion port. I wouldn't consider duplicating this socket safe, unless you're 100% sure there's no chance of some other code trying to associate it with a second I/O completion port; I know that the 2.0 .NET Socket class does use an IOCP internally for async operations, though that may have changed in later versions.

Answer (score 3):

You can probably use the `PROTOCOL_INFO` structure returned by [`WSADuplicateSocket()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741565%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), convert it to its [`SocketInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketinformation.aspx) equivalent and then use the [appropriate socket constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145125.aspx) to get a shared socket with a different handle.

The "Remarks" section in the documentation on [`WSADuplicateSocket()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741565%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) depicts the usual control flow involved in socket duplication.  I think this flow is somewhat equivalent to the [`SocketInformation Socket::DuplicateAndClose()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.duplicateandclose.aspx) and  [`Socket(SocketInformation)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145125.aspx) pair of calls.