# Boost::asio::socket how to get int or uint from it that would be crossplatformly assignable back?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

So we have some [function like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671586/how-to-create-a-boost-asio-socket-from-a-native-socket/1671703#1671703):

```
void SendData (/* what goes here if we can only send to our function C POD types like int, uint etc? */ socket, std::string message)
{
    boost::asio::io_service ioserv;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket s(ioserv);
    s.assign(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), socket);
    s.send(boost::asio::buffer(message));
}
```

and from some other function we want to call `SendData`  having some `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket sock`... so something like:

```
//...
SendData(/* what goes here? Is there any sock.getInt() */, "message");
//...
```

So what are my options for this? What simple C POD types can be taken from boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket that could be later reinterpreted with `.assign`?

Comment: The contents of the buffer are not translated on the wire, so sending an `int` from one machine to another can be read directly in if the platforms are compatible.  If they are not, then the receiving device will need to translate the byte ordering.

Comment: Uh, why not `socket*` (or `void*` then casted to `socket*`)?

Answer (score -1):

> What simple C POD types can be taken from `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket`
>   that could be later reinterpreted with `assign()`?

[`socket::native()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/native.html) returns the native representation of what was passed to [`socket::assign()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/assign/overload1.html). On Linux and Mac OS X this is an integer, I don't know about Windows.